# Dispatch is not defined in redux with reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, flux

I want to know why clicking on the table row would still give me undefined dispatch error which leads to `Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function`. I have been following this [post](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/916) to try and fix the problem, but so far no success.

ListingTable.js

```
import Table from 'grommet/components/Table';
import React from 'react';
import {remove, add} from '../action/ListAction';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

let createHandlers = function(dispatch) {
    let onClick = function(item) {
        dispatch(add(item)) <<== undefined!!!!
    };
    return {
        onClick
    };
};
export class ListingTable extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handlers = createHandlers(this.props.dispatch);
    }
    render() {
        return <Table>
                <tbody>
                {
                    this.props.data.map((item, key)=>
                        (
                            // Undefined Error!!!!
                            <tr onClick={()=> this.handlers.onClick(item)} key={key}>

                                <td>{item.user_name}</td>
                                <td>{item.name}</td>
                                <td>{item.url}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))
                }
                </tbody>
            </Table>
    }
}

export default connect()(ListingTable)
```

app.js

```
import { ListingTable } from './component/ListingTable';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import reducer from '../reducer/ListingReducer'

export default class Page extends React.Component {
   render() {
      <Provider store={createStore(reducer)}>
         <ListingTable data={this.props.item}/>
      </Provider>
   }
}
```

I saw that the store object is present in the debug console, but it isn't passed to the ListingTable component:

[image]

Comment: `import ListingTable from './'`  imports value on default export while `import { ListingTable } from './'` imports value by its name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are importing not connected component.

remove `export` before `class ListingTable`

```
class ListingTable extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handlers = createHandlers(this.props.dispatch);
  }
  render() {
    return <Table>
            <tbody>
            {
                this.props.data.map((item, key)=>
                    (
                        // Undefined Error!!!!
                        <tr onClick={()=> this.handlers.onClick(item)} key={key}>

                            <td>{item.user_name}</td>
                            <td>{item.name}</td>
                            <td>{item.url}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))
            }
            </tbody>
        </Table>
  }
}

export default connect()(ListingTable)
```

app.js

```
import ListingTable from './component/ListingTable';
```

Comment: With typescript / ES6, I also had to change my imports from
`import { ListingTable } from '..'` to `import ListingTable from '..'`. 

Very subtle, I guess now I know how `export default` works.